# How to display data to table in React Js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, html-table

I'm trying to display some data received through API to table in React Js, data is received as object so I can't map trough it. What would be the best practice in this situation? For now the data is hardcoded, but it needs to be dynamic.

My code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-water-w4mmm?file=/src/App.js:24-1182)

```
export default function App() {

  const data ={
    
    "people" :[
      {
        "name":"John",
        "last_name":"Doe",
        "age":"25",
        "Occupation":"driver",
      },
      {
        "name":"Jack",
        "last_name":"Brown",
        "age":"24",
        "Occupation":"it"
      },
      {
        "name":"Oliver",
        "last_name":"Black",

        "age":"30",
        "Occupation":"cto"
      },
    ],

    "format":{"last_name":"Last Name"}
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <table>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Name</td>
           <td>John</td>
           <td>Jack</td>
           <td>Oliver</td>
           
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Last Name</td>
           <td>Doe</td>
           <td>Brown</td>
           <td>Black</td>
           
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Age</td>
           <td>25</td>
           <td>24</td>
           <td>30</td>
           
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Occupation</td>
           <td>driver</td>
           <td>it</td>
           <td>ceo</td>
         </tr>

         
       </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

needs to be displayed as

```
Name         John     Jack      Oliver
Last Name    Doe      Brown     Black
Age          25       24        30
Occupation   driver   it        ceo
```

I can't figure out how to display the data dynamically ( and also add data from **format** part. I would appreciate any suggestion and help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The root problem is,** normalize your data from `flat data` into `dynamic/aggregated data` by horizontal `key` & `values` as the following structure

```
[
  {
    "Name": [
      "John",
      "Jack",
      "Oliver"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Last Name": [
      "Doe",
      "Brown",
      "Black"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Age": [
      "25",
      "24",
      "30"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Occupation": [
      "driver",
      "it",
      "cto"
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
const data ={
    "people" :[
      {
        "name":"John",
        "last_name":"Doe",
        "age":"25",
        "Occupation":"driver",
      },
      {
        "name":"Jack",
        "last_name":"Brown",
        "age":"24",
        "Occupation":"it"
      },
      {
        "name":"Oliver",
        "last_name":"Black",

        "age":"30",
        "Occupation":"cto"
      },
    ],

    "format":{"last_name":"Last Name"}
  };
var items  = Object.values(data)[0];

var createOrEdit = (acc, key, value) => {
    var findItem = acc.find(r => r[key] !== undefined);
    if(findItem == undefined)
      acc.push({[key]: [value]});
    else
      findItem[key].push(value);
    
    return acc;
}

var result = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    createOrEdit(acc, 'Name', curr.name);
    createOrEdit(acc, 'Last Name', curr.last_name);
    createOrEdit(acc, 'Age', curr.age);    
    createOrEdit(acc, 'Occupation', curr.Occupation);
    
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
  
for(let item of result){
  console.log(Object.keys(item)[0]);
  console.log(Object.values(item)[0]);
}
```

After that, you can easily render data based on normalized data like below

```js
const nomorlizeData = (data) => {
  var items = Object.values(data)[0];

  var createOrEdit = (acc, key, value) => {
    var findItem = acc.find((r) => r[key] !== undefined);
    if (findItem === undefined) acc.push({ [key]: [value] });
    else findItem[key].push(value);

    return acc;
  };

  var result = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    createOrEdit(acc, "Name", curr.name);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Last Name", curr.last_name);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Age", curr.age);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Occupation", curr.Occupation);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return result;
};

function App() {
  const data = {
    people: [
      {
        name: "John",
        last_name: "Doe",
        age: "25",
        Occupation: "driver"
      },
      {
        name: "Jack",
        last_name: "Brown",
        age: "24",
        Occupation: "it"
      },
      {
        name: "Oliver",
        last_name: "Black",

        age: "30",
        Occupation: "cto"
      }
    ],

    format: { last_name: "Last Name" }
  };

  var renderData = (items) =>
    items.map((r) => {
      var key = <td>{Object.keys(r)[0]}</td>;
      var values = Object.values(r)[0].map((v) => <td>{v}</td>);
      return (
        <tr>
          {key}
          {values}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>{renderData(nomorlizeData(data))}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[Codesanbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sara-e7hx3?file=/src/App.js:23-1454)

Comment: hi, sorry to bother, but I have additional question, could you please help me with it? Basically, I forgot to add id to the data, and now I need to add id to each <td> element. I updated CodeSandbox with id.                     https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rain-7o2v2                                                                                                                            I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I'm busy now. I'll get back to you soon. Bro. Maybe tmr morning ^^!

Comment: Hi @nika, what does the new structure & expected data/result you want to display?

Comment: If your expected result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkbkU.png), You just need to add `createOrEdit(acc, "id", curr.id);` into your code.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. No, i wanted to add id to the <td> cell, like <td id={id}> value </td>. I don't know if that's possible though.

Answer (score 5):

My approach is somewhat unorthodox, but may still be of interest to you. I would actually render your data like so first:

```
Name    Last Name   Age Occupation
John    Doe         25  driver
Jack    Brown       24  it
Oliver  Black       30  cto
```

And then simply use CSS to transpose it, which will give it the look you want:

```
Name         John     Jack      Oliver
Last Name    Doe      Brown     Black
Age          25       24        30
Occupation   driver   it        ceo
```

So, the render part is super easy:

```
    <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Occupation</th>
          </tr>
          {data.people.map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.last_name}</td>
              <td>{item.age}</td>
              <td>{item.Occupation}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
    </tbody>
```

So is the CSS part:

```
tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
th,td {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

That's it. Oh, here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kapitsa-zlg2p?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Personally, I don't like the `"trick"` like this. You should normalize the data first.

Comment: @Phong You had already posted a way that involved normalizing. Would you rather I repost your answer? Just wanted to give a different solutions to the problem.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, your trick is another option. But there are many ways to normalize data, I think :D.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works! https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ie2rt6

```
import React from "react";

const Table = ({ headers, data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {headers.map(head => (
              <th>{head}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <tr>
              {headers.map(head => (
                <td>{row[head]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Your solution is too complex. Must use too much 3rd lib without knowing behind the sense ==> Too bad for your logical thinking.

Comment: Firstly, Your data and structure are irrelevant with OP. Secondly, You should explain some parts involve in your answer. It makes me too hard to be able to understand :(